# How to resize the image before uploading to cloudinary?

Tags: image, meteor, cloudinary

This is my first time to post a question here. I was building a meteor app with image uploading functions. I found a cloudinary package for meteor https://github.com/Lepozepo/cloudinary and it works pretty well. The only and the biggest problem I have is the resizing of image. By default this package will upload the original image taken from phone, which is often 3 or 4 MB and whose size is around 2000x4000, but I only want image to a few KBs. And because of this problem, it takes so much storage and bandwidth for the app. What should I do to fix this problem ? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 8):

I am not sure if anybody needs this but i was struggling with this for the past 2 days and could not find a solution. Finally i went to cloudinary dashboard and it was the simplest thing ever. Login to your cloudinary. Go to settings -> upload -> Upload presets: edit(on your project) -> upload manipulations -> Incoming Transformation: edit -> change the imcoming image as you like :D.

I uploaded an image 2mb in size and it came down to 30kb after applying incoming transformation.

Hope this helps someone :)

Answer (score 2):

If you're performing client-side uploads (via Cloudinary's jQuery integration library), you can perform a client-side resize before the upload:
https://github.com/cloudinary/cloudinary_js#client-side-image-resizing-before-upload

If you're performing server-side uploads, you can apply an [incoming transformation](http://cloudinary.com/documentation/node_image_upload#incoming_transformations) to transform (resize) the image before storing it in your Cloudinary account.

Incoming transformations can be set in upload presets too:
http://cloudinary.com/blog/centralized_control_for_image_upload_image_size_format_thumbnail_generation_tagging_and_more